# How can I read and import .txt file into database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a `.txt` file on our webserver which gets updated and replaced by the client's third party property software.

Does anyone have a script (PHP/MySQL) where I can read this file and import it into a table in my database? Ideally something using codeigniter, but standard PHP will work just fine too.

It is in this format:

```
"BranchID","PropertyID","PropertyName","Street","DisplayStreet","Postcode","PricePrefix","Price","Bedrooms","Receptions","Bathrooms","ParkingSpaces","Numeric5","Numeric6","Numeric7","Numeric8","Numeric9","AREA","TYPE","FURNISHED","CHILDREN","SMOKING","PETS","GARDEN","DSS","PARKING","cFacility1","cFacility2","cFacility3","cFacility4","cFacility5","cFacility6","cFacility7","cFacility8","cFacility9","cFacility10","Tenure","ShortDescription","MainDescription","AvailabilityCode","AvailabilityDate","FullAddress","PricePrefixPos"
```

My field names match these headers exactly.

Comment: isn't that txt a csv in fact?

Comment: yes, same format... but the file is 'xfile.txt'

Comment: that doesn't matter.. I was talking about the format.. if you rename it to .jpg it doesn't make it a picture.. there are a number of solutions to import csv into the database (and you already have answers) I just figured people would understand better if you clear this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MYSQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` directly, see [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

This will save come scripting time and will be much faster than importing it via a PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

You may also parse it with PHP.
It looks like a csv.

I would use [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse the file.